# understanding updateWithOnConflict

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with a simple database.  It has three columns.  _id (integer primary key autoincrement), jobnumber (text unique not null) and jobpart (text not null).

Everything works fine until I try and update a record and enter an existing jobnumber.  When I do that the app crashes and I get a force close.

I'm using updateWithOnConflict and I thought that caused things to exit gracefully and return a code.  Not sure if I'm merely not understanding or if I've done something wrong...

Any help appreciated.

update code snippet:

```
    public int updateJob(long rowId, String jobnumber, String jobpart) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(JOB_NUMBER, jobnumber);
        args.put(JOB_PART, jobpart);

        return mDb.updateWithOnConflict(JOB_TABLE, args, JOB_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ROLLBACK);
    }
```

output from LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot commit - no transaction is active
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeSql(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:89)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1933)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1864)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:688)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:266)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:96)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1829)
at cdc.gridtest.ScheduleDBAdapter.updateJob(ScheduleDBAdapter.java:325)
at cdc.gridtest.JobEdit.saveState(JobEdit.java:104)
at cdc.gridtest.JobEdit.access$0(JobEdit.java:90)
at cdc.gridtest.JobEdit$1.onClick(JobEdit.java:47)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you use `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ROLLBACK` flag but you do not use a transaction. You should either create a transaction or put `CONFLICT_IGNORE` as a flag in your method call.

Comment: That was indeed the fix.  Since all the work from this app will be done one row at a time, I have no need for anything other than CONFLICT_IGNORE (something I didn't really consider until you made me think about it with your answer).  Thanks!

Comment: CONFLICT_IGNORE does this catch the throw and leave the OLD DATA, or does it replace the NEW DATA ? Either it should use an insert or update query.