# UI update failed after broadcast service in android

Tags: android

I am trying to sync data to server using broadcast services. When user is online there is no issue but when they go online from offline(or flight mode) service is unfortuntly stop but data is saved to server.
In **RecyclerAdapter.java**  i am updating image from stopwatch to success its not working

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    int sync_status = arrayList.get(position).getSync_status();
    if(sync_status==DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK){
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.success);
    }else {
        holder.Sync_Status.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopwatch);
    }

}
```

here is my **MainActivity.java**

where i call onReceive method of broadcast service. And two methods onStart() and onPause().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText Name;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Contact> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        Name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        readFromLocalStorage();

        broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                readFromLocalStorage();

            }
        };


    }
    public void submitName(View view){

        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        saveToAppServer(name);
        Name.setText("");
    }


    private void readFromLocalStorage() {

        arrayList.clear();
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);
        //String[] columns = {DbContact.NAME, DbContact.SYNC_STATUS};
       // Cursor cursor = database.query(DbContact.TABLE_NAME,
              //  columns,
               // null,
              //  null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.NAME));
            int sync_status=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS));

            arrayList.add(new Contact(name,sync_status));

        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private void saveToAppServer(final String name){
        if(checkNetworkConnection()){

            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DbContact.SERVER_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");

                                if(Response.equals("OK")){
                                    saveToLocalStorage(name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK);
                                }
                                else{
                                    saveToLocalStorage(name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    saveToLocalStorage(name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);


                }
            })

            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    return params;
                }
            }  ;

            VolleySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        }
        else{

            saveToLocalStorage(name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);


        }




    }
    public boolean checkNetworkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo!= null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    private void saveToLocalStorage(String name, int sync){

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(name, sync, database);
        readFromLocalStorage();
        dbHelper.close();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DbContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

**NetworkMonitor.java**

```
public class NetworkMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(checkNetworkConnection(context)){

            final DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);
            final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor=dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS));
                if(sync_status == DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED){
                    final String Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.NAME));
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DbContact.SERVER_URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");

                                        if(Response.equals("OK")){
                                            dbHelper.updateLocalDatabase(Name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK,database);
                                            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DbContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));


                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("name",Name);
                            return params;
                        }
                    } ;
                    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                }
            }

            dbHelper.close();
        }

    }

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo!= null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

}
```

Logcat error:

```
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1662)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1639)
at net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.oneMore.DbHelper.updateLocalDatabase(DbHelper.java:85)
at net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.oneMore.NetworkMonitor$1.onResponse(NetworkMonitor.java:51)
at net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.oneMore.NetworkMonitor$1.onResponse(NetworkMonitor.java:43)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is your activtiy available in foreground?

Comment: yes, it is in a foreground

Comment: What is your error log? Have you tried to debug you code?

Comment: edit it, please check error log

Comment: I am trying to debug it.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956636/1270865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This might be cause of multiple instantiation of `DbHelper` class.* Make sure you're instantiating DbHelper class for only once.
Here is the example of possible approach to overcome this issue,

**Manage your DbHelper class as a singleton-**

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
    private SQLiteDatabase jewlotDB;

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "my_db.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
     * make call to static method "getInstance()" instead.
     */
    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // your stuffs
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // do your creating stuffs here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        // open the database...
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            jewlotDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // check the state of db ??....
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return jewlotDB != null && jewlotDB.isOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (jewlotDB != null)
            jewlotDB.close();
        super.close();
    }

    public void updateLocalDatabase(String name, int sync_status) {
        if (!isOpen()) openDataBase();

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS, sync_status);
        String selection = DbContact.NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {name};
        database.update(DbContact.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, selection, selection_args);
        database.close();
    }
}
```

The static `getInstance()` method ensures that only one `DatabaseHelper` will ever exist at any given time. If the `sInstance` object has not been initialized.

You should not initialize your helper object using with new `DatabaseHelper(context)`! Instead, always use `DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)`, as it guarantees that only one database helper will exist across the entire application’s lifecycle.

[Reference Blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)

Comment: In NetWorkMonitor  instead of             final DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);             final DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper.getInstance(context);  show error

Comment: @Priya, Replace `DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);` with `DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)` in whole application and let me know what happens, because this is good practice to deal with DatabaseHelper classes

Comment: public void updateLocalDatabase(String name, int sync_status, SQLiteDatabase database){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS,sync_status);
        String selection = DbContact.NAME +" LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args={name};
        database.update(DbContact.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,selection,selection_args);
    }        on updateToLocalDatabase

Comment: Alright, edited my code. as you can see your updated `updateLocalDatabase` method - we doesn't acquiring Database as parameter, instead we are opening an closing `database` within our method. Two more method is there if you want to add them in your `DatabaseHelper`. Dig deep, m sure you'll get it.

Comment: The reason was `dbHelper.close();` statement, that written in onReceive method. `onResponse` will be called after closing a database. while you were calling `dbHelper.updateLocalDatabase(Name,DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK,database);` in `onResponse`. So before executing that line database will get closed. Anyways.. if the answer is useful - you can upvote as well as accept it as a correct answer. you're welcome btw.